# Scrivener stopped working after Windows 10 or 11 update

Tags: windows, incompatibility, ivona

I've used Scrivener as a writing tool for upwards of 8 years. I had hung on to Windows 7 because as a systems developer and Internet grandfather[1] with 50+ years experience I wished to avoid Windows 10 intrusive practices.[2]  I updated from Windows 7 to 10 because my LaTeX distribution, MikTex, stopped it's compatibility with Windows 7.[3]

After updating to Windows 10 my Scrivener 3 install no longer started. I noticed in Process Explorer 64 that Scrivener started but then collided with Ivona text-to-speech processor, then died. I use Scrivener a lot for writing books, technical documents and how-tos, in conjunction with LaTeX on Intellisense Idea. *Putting this Q up for solutions because I've noticed other Scrivener users have had this problem*.

**Is there a way to resolve this issue?** I don't need, and don't like (detest) Ivona because I've used Dragon Naturally speaking for too long. I get the feeling, though, that there must be some other way to resolve a software conflict than by removing software installed as part of Windows.[4] Apart from the Scrivener/Ivona conflict, Defender flags CCleaner as a PUA and removes references to it automatically.

**On a wider note**, is there a "best practice", when it comes to upgrading Windows, that avoids it removing or stopping a user's chosen tools? I've used Windows since the 1985 original but never discovered the answer.

[1] I've used Internet since the '70s on-and-off. With Comcast (I think) I used mail systems in the early '80s. I'm old and don't like to be pushed around.
[2] Laws against slavery have existed a long time. Using people's physical->digital energy in the form of keypresses and site information interest by enforced contract seems tantamount to slavery in which all the benefit and reward goes one way. Going further, to enforce a user's software tools by denying some of them, is a gross interference.
[3] Shame on MikTex developers for deserting backward compatibility of such a widely used distribution.

Comment: I note the '-1' first score as being "No research effort, unclear or not useful", but without comment. In fact I searched with "Scrivener stopped working after Windows 10" before posting. There are many people who suffered the same problem. Solutions mostly concerned removing the C distributable or reinstalling Scrivener, neither of which deals with the problem.

Answer (score -1):

***My solution was to remove all Ivona installs***:  Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> right-click on software package -> uninstall. Scrivener 3 then worked.

Apart from the frustration and obvious waste of time caused by Microsoft, there is no need to interfere with well known products. I lost CCleaner too, permanently, after about a decade of satisfactory use.

[4] This will probably push me to abandon Windows in favour of Linux on my main system, used for serious development. All my other systems use Linux.

**Update 29Dec23**
I'm guessing whoever marked this down is from Windows or Ivona. A read of Windows upgrade information, or a search on "windows.old" quickly reveals that upgrading Windows, say from Windows 7 to Windows 10, produces a "windows.old" folder containing "removed" software. In my case that included Ccleaner, Ivona and other software I'd used for many years. Unfortunately, Microsoft deletes the *windows.old* folder after a month. I didn't catch it in time because that part was not abundantly obvious. I lost my software, including lifetime rights as an early adopter in some cases. That represents a direct interference with a computer and a breach of statutory law (UK:  Computer Misuse Act, for example). Even today, having reinstalled Ccleaner on one system for testing and review purposes, Microsoft marks Cleaner as a *potential* threat and interferes with it's operation. My favourite software, Scrivener, mainly used for computer science papers and booklets, went that way too.

I have abandoned Windows after using it since pre-release in 198(4?).